# Clean image rendering in flash player

Tags: image, flash, pixelate

Ladies/ Gentlemen

We are building a flash based product where we need to create icons for various modules. we are having challenges in look and feel of the icons- what looks really good on Adobe Illustrator/ Photoshop looks jagged on flashPlayer. A challenge we have is that the overall screen aspect ratio and hence aspect for the icons which are relatively sized can change

we were told in discussions with some adobe folks that 
a) we need to build icons which are square, and in multiples of 32 pixels. 
b) use a png format

As per them, this way the pixelation is reduced and diagonal lines won't appear jagged- we still have an issue on rendering in flash player

Any ideas/ guidance on how to approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**6 hours and no answer?**

Here's the magical property you want: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Bitmap.html#smoothing

Just make that `true`, either via the setter, or via the constructor.

Comment: i am using png graphics as per recommendation and a pixel in muktiples of 32... this note seems to be very different - unable to reconcile the two...

Comment: When you import the bitmap (png), just set the property. It doesn't matter what size your image is, or what format it is in.

Comment: This works perfectly- Thanks a ton... was chasing down a bunch of false alleys